# Show pR[x] + (x) is a prime ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I am self studying the notes [here](http://web.mit.edu/18.705/www/13Ed.pdf). The problem is exercise 2.18 on page 9 (solutions provided there as well).

> Let R be a ring, p a prime ideal, R[X] the polynomial ring, pR[x] the product ideal and (x) the ideal generated by x. We want to show that pR[x] + (x) is a prime ideal.

In the solutions they state that (pR[x] + (x))/(pR[x]) = (x) ⊂ (R/p)[x]. This is the part I do not understand (I believe I follow the rest of the solution). Presumably this is obvious since there is no additional justification provided...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define

$$\phi: pR[x]+(x)\to (x)\;,\;\;\phi(pf(x)+xg(x)):=xg(x)$$

Show the above is a surjective ring homomorphism (of rings without unity) and its kernel is $\;pR[x]\;$ , and now apply the first isomorphism theorem

Comment: Thank you for your clear solution.